# R: create function or loop to change values based on two (or more) conditions

Tags: r, function, if-statement

As you can probably see from the age of my account, i'm new here.

I'm running into problems with creating a function or loop to replace single values in a row, based on 2 or more conditions. Here is my sample dataset:

`date         timeslot  volume  lag1
1  2018-01-17    3       553   296
2  2018-01-17    4       NA    553
3  2018-01-18    1       NA     NA
4  2018-01-18    2       NA     NA
5  2018-01-18    3       NA     NA
6  2018-01-18    4       NA     NA`

types are: Date, int, num, num

i want to create a function that replaces the NA from lag1 with the average of the last 5 simmulair timeslots. This value is calculated with:

```
w <- as.integer(mean(tail(data$volume[data$timeslot %in% c(1)],5), na.rm =TRUE ))
```

if i create a `if` or `for` loop, it returns `"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"`

So far i can only change all the lag1 values, or non.

The function should be something like this: if lag1 == NA & timeslot  ==1 then change that row's value to `w`

What i have tried so far:

```
for(i in data$lag1){
  if(data$timeslot== '1'){
    data$lag1[is.na(data$lag1)]<-w
  }else(data$lag1<-data$lag1)
}
```

and also:

```
data$lag1<- ifelse(data$timeslot== "1", is.na(data$lag1)<-w, data$lag1 )
```

This does work, but it changes all the values at once. It should only change the 1 value that is in the same row as the timeslot.

Most of the time it will return the error above. I suspect that it has something to do with the "timeslot" column.

i tried a few different things, but seeing that i like a clean R environment, most of them have been deleted

i can't seem to figure this one out. Hope you guys can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You've mentioned a couple of things you've tried, but you haven't shown the code that produced the error. There are several ways to achieve what you're after, but it's often best to learn by seeing the one or two reasons your code isn't working, rather than having an entirely new solution presented to you.

Comment: Hi @rosscova Thank you! I updated the original post with some additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Overview

I created the `ReplaceNALag1WithSimilarRecentTimeslots()` function to replace NA `df$lag1` values with the average of the last 5 `df$lag1` values for each unique `df$timeslot` value.

The use of [`sapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) was helpful in using `ReplaceNALag1WithSimilarRecentTimeslots()` once, since it **applies** the logic to each element in X. In this case, X is a vector of unique `df$timeslot` values whose row also contains an NA `df$lag1` value.

[`NaN`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/is.finite.html) are introduced due to the reproducible data containing no recent non NA `df$lag1` values.

```
# create data frame
df <- 
  data.frame(
    date = as.Date( x = c( 
      paste("2018"
            , "01"
            , rep( x = "17", times = 2 )
            , sep = "-" 
      )
      , paste( "2018"
               , "01"
               , rep( x = "18", times = 4 )
               , sep = "-" 
      )
    ) 
    )
    , timeslot = as.integer( c( 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 ) )
    , volume = c( 533, rep( x = NA, times = 5 ) )
    , lag1 = c( 296, 553, rep( x = NA, times = 4 ) )
    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# ensure that the data frame
# is ordered by date,
# so that rows with a date value closer to today
# appear at the end of the data frame
df <- df[ order( df$date ) , ]

# view results
df
#         date timeslot volume lag1
# 1 2018-01-17        3    533  296
# 2 2018-01-17        4     NA  553
# 3 2018-01-18        1     NA   NA
# 4 2018-01-18        2     NA   NA
# 5 2018-01-18        3     NA   NA
# 6 2018-01-18        4     NA   NA


# create a function that
# replaces NA lag1 values
# with the average of the
# last 5 lag1 values for 
# each unique timeslot value
ReplaceNALag1WithSimilarRecentTimeslots <- function( unique.timeslot.value ){

  # create condition that 
  # that pulls out non NAs from lag1 for a particular timeslot
  # but that only gives us the 5 most recent values
  # assuming that elements that appear at the end of vector
  # are more recent than elements that appear near the beginning of the vector
  non.na.lag1.condition.by.timeslot <- 
    tail(
      x = which( !is.na( df$lag1 ) & df$timeslot == unique.timeslot.value )
      , n = 5
    )

  # calculate the average lag1 value
  # for those similar non NA lag1 values
  # for that particular timeslot
  mean( df$lag1[ non.na.lag1.condition.by.timeslot ] ) 


} # end of ReplaceNALag1WithSimilarRecentTimeslots() function

# create the NA lag1 condition
na.lag1.condition <- which( is.na( df$lag1 ) )

# use ReplaceNALag1WithSimilarRecentTimeslots()
# on those NA lag1 values
df$lag1[ na.lag1.condition ] <-
  sapply( X = unique( df$timeslot[ na.lag1.condition ] )
          , FUN = function( i ) ReplaceNALag1WithSimilarRecentTimeslots( i )
          , simplify = TRUE
          , USE.NAMES = TRUE
          )

# View the results
df
#         date timeslot volume lag1
# 1 2018-01-17        3    533  296
# 2 2018-01-17        4     NA  553
# 3 2018-01-18        1     NA  NaN
# 4 2018-01-18        2     NA  NaN
# 5 2018-01-18        3     NA  296
# 6 2018-01-18        4     NA  553

# end of script #
```

Comment: Thank you! that actually works way better than i got it to work. The dataset that i'm using is way bigger than the sample set, so it should be able to return values for all the missing Lag1 point.

Comment: @Androssie, I've updated the answer to avoid copying and pasting multiple conditions. Let me know how it works for you!

Comment: @aspiringurbandatascientiest Thank you! that works great! It looks and works a lot smoother than your first solution (which worked fine for me as well haha). Thank you very much!

Comment: @Androssie Haha I'm glad it works! Good luck with the rest of your project!